# Oracle - What does "Bytes" in query plan stands for each record/entry in query plan for given query?

Tags: oracle

I was trying to understand different parameters involved in query execution plan for table and view related queries in Oracle. One of the parameter which I am not able to fully understand is "Bytes".

Let say I have created a table with 1M records which has two columns (integer, varchar2). Now I try to check query plan for that table with rownum <= 100. Below is query and query plan for same:

**Query:**

> Select * from test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_table1 where ROWNUM <= 100;

**Query plan:**

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost (%CPU) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 100 | 51500 | 5 (20) |
| *1 | COUNT STOPKEY |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | TEST_TABLE1 | 832K | 408M | 5 (20) |

From the same table I created a view with col1, col2 and count(col1) columns with group by clause. Below is the query plan for view with rownum <= 100:

**Query:**

> Select * from test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_view2 where ROWNUM <= 100;

**Query plan:**

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost (%CPU) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 100 | 51500 | 17655(1) |
| *1 | COUNT STOPKEY |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | VIEW | TEST_VIEW2 | 832K | 419M | 17655(1) |
| *3 | SORT GROUP BY STOPKEY |  | 832K | 408M | 17655(1) |
| *4 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | TEST_TABLE1 | 832K | 408M | 17655(1) |

**Note:** Let me know if table and view creation queries or any other information is required. Thanks!!

From the query plan for table and view I want to know following things:

- Number of bytes for "TABLE ACCESS FULL" for TEST_TABLE1 shows 408M in "Bytes" section. Will it actually processes this much amount of data/bytes on DB site when I try to run mentioned select query for TEST_TABLE1. Also for Id (0) -> SELECT STATEMENT I could see 51500 in "Bytes" section. So will it load those many additional bytes along with 408M?
- Similarly for view there are different values for "Bytes" for different Ids, Mainly I want to know if it would access around 408M data on db side in order to run simple select * query with top 100 rows?

I tried to find this info with different articles from oracle and stackoverflow and other places but somehow I am not able to understand the "Bytes" part in Query plan.

**Edit:**

- Oracle version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Something doesn't look right, in your first (and simplest) Explain plan. With the "count stopkey" operation, the FULL TABLE ACCESS step should show the same cardinality and number of bytes as the SELECT operation - it should NOT show the total cardinality and number of bytes for the full table. Are you sure you didn't mix some things up here?

Comment: Create table qry:

CREATE TABLE test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_table1(col1 int, col2 varchar2(1000));

DECLARE
    col2 CHAR(1000);
BEGIN
    FOR col1 IN 1 .. 1000000 LOOP
            col2 := chr(39) || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890' || col1 || chr(39);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO  test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_table1 VALUES ('|| col1 ||', ' || col2 || ')';
        END LOOP;
END;

Comment: Create view query:

CREATE VIEW test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_view2 as select col1, col2, count(col1) col1_count from test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_table1 where col1 >= 10 group by col1, col2;

Comment: Hi @mathguy, I have added create table + insertion and create view script. After executing those script I had captured execution plan for table and view using following queries:

Table:
Select * from test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_table1 where ROWNUM <= 100;

View:
Select * from test_tablescan_bytes_check.test_view2 where ROWNUM <= 100;

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It is the amount of data processed in each individual step. Yes, it will access 408M of data with `TABLE ACCESS FULL`, because it believes that it needs to process every row in the table. I second mathguy's question though about the explain plan you posted: when I test this I don't see a full tablescan, but rather a `STORAGE FULL FIRST ROWS` operation that only grabs 100 rows of data.

That said, `ROWNUM` is a construct that only applies to the *result set*, not the data in the table, which is unordered. Your query will search the entire table, and return the first *randomly ordered* 100 rows returned. It will *not* be the "first 100 rows" in the table because no order has been applied to the data by default.

As written, your view will always have a higher cost than selecting rows directly from the table: you're performing summary calculations on the data in the table, and it must complete the entire result set before it can select the first 100 rows of that set.

Comment: Hi @pmdba,

Thank you for your reply!!

Is there a way to avoid full table scan/data access? Our requirement is to get 100 or 10k records from table/view (any record is fine, we are looking for just sample) using oracle jdbc driver and we won't have any filter condition (except rownum) as we don't have information about any other filter when we try to get 100 or 10k records. Thanks!!

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production